# Is there anything that can be done in C and not in C++ and the opposite way

Tags: c++, c

Referring to C and C++ . I wanted to know if there is anything that is possible in one of the languages and impossible in the other.

Some thoughts I had on the subject:

- My first thought was the they since they both are translated to assembly, actually it should be possible to do everything we want in both languages.
- But hesitating about it since C++ is a higher level language so it might not expose creating all possibilities C does and C might not expose all possible in assembly etc. As the language is higher in my opinion it is easier for the programmer but computation power is decreased. is this correct?
- And in the other way around is there anything possible in C++ and not in C-
  I'm not referring to code efficiency and usability of the programmer (aware of polymorphism, inheritance etc.) but want to know is there's anything that is impossible in C.
- Another fact to emphasize that anything possible in C is possible in C++ is using the wrappers of C++ for C libraries (is this considered pure C++ programing ?)
  (is C++ built over C? )

I'll be happy for some clarification of this subject.

Thanks!

Comment: C++ is a roughly a superset of C, it is not a "higher level language than C" per se.

Comment: The trouble with the question is that it says "anything that can be done".  For example, `C` cannot overload operators.  Maybe you want to limit what "anything" means?

Comment: Both languages are Turing-complete.  Any abstract computation expressible in one is expressible in the other.

Comment: @cdhowie - I disagree with "not a higher level language", though not very strongly. For example, late binding dispatch is basically a kind of decision handling that is implemented by the compiler, but which in C would have to be coded manually. There are a number of issues like this which mean there is a bigger gap between the source code and the machine in C++ than in C - though the difference isn't exactly huge IMO. There's the question of what *precisely* higher level means, though - e.g. the C++ support for cleaner wrapping of library abstractions.

Comment: You need to ask a clearer question here. Do you mean syntactic language features? Types of software you can build? Or literally equivalency of computation?

Comment: @Stephen: Neither language is Turing complete. `sizeof(void *)` is finite (and like all types, `void *` has a representation in units of `unsigned char`). This means the memory storage is finite. `sizeof(long)` is finite. This means the addressable content of any given file is finite. The size of strings is limited by `size_t`, so the number of possible filenames/files is finite. Thus, unlike many other languages which may be finite in implementation but formally Turing-complete, C and C++ **formally** describe finite-state machines (mainly due to the "representation of types" as `char`).

Answer (score 14):

In the sense that they're both Turing-complete languages, the answer is no.

Comment: +1 - though I think the differences in how library abstractions can be made available to users are still significant.

Comment: @Steve314: Certainly, I wouldn't argue otherwise.

Comment: @Noah: +1 :) In the sense that it's Turing-complete, however, there's nevertheless nothing you can compute in C that you can't compute in Brainfuck. That doesn't mean that I think all games, for example, should be written in Brainfuck.

Answer (score 2):

Both C and C++ are turing complete, so you can express any abstract computation in both of them. Concrete computations (fiddling with hardware bits) is an entirely different story, so e.g. you couldn't implement what is commonly regarded as an operating system in Ruby.

Both C and C++ are sufficiently close to the metal though that you can program at hardware bit level with both of them.

Also, C++ doesn't hide anything from you that C doesn't, at least if you want to deal with all the hairy details.

Comment: C++ hides the implementation of it's virtual function dispatch mechanism. Obviously that doesn't exist in C, but it may be worth a mention, if only so I can whine about one of my pet peaves - I think there are circumstances where explicit access to (and adding non-standard members to) the virtual table might be useful and, in a language with the overall philosophy of C++, should be possible. BTW - I already know the standard doesn't mandate virtual tables, and I haven't thought this through properly so it may be a daft (or just pointless) idea.

Answer (score 1):

Both are Turing complete so both can solve the same problems.

However C++ is *almost* a superset of C. Anything you can write in C can easily be written in C++ in a very similar way, usually requiring no changes at all, or occasionally requiring small changes. The reverse is not true - there are things you can write in C++ that are difficult (but not impossible) to convert directly to C. Examples are object oriented programming (polymorphism, multiple inheritance, etc...), exceptions, and so on.

Comment: Actually, polymorphism is really straight-forward to do in C. Inheritance is hard. Templates ... I have no clue how you can do in C. But there's a difference between mirroring code vs. mirroring a program's behaviour.

Comment: I am sure it is easy to write a C++ -> C compiler. Then compile the code as C. You may have to write some glue code (but that should already be available in g++ code somewhere.

Comment: @MartinYork Actually, I think that's a very good idea. If you write a compiler from _any_ language to C, then you essentially got that language to be as portable as C. You do depend on a C compiler, but that's a cheap dependency to my taste.

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* do this in C++ but you *can* in C

```
int* ptr = malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
```

C++ makes you explicitly cast the void *

And of course in C, anything to do with object orientation <strike>cannot be done.</strike> is like pounding a square peg through a round hole.

Comment: Almost. You can fake OO with structs, functions and function pointer, but basically it boils down to doing writing yourself what is normally syntactic sugar in C++.

Comment: Well, implicit casting is just a language characteristic, and is not at all related to what you can express on a hardware level with the language.

Comment: -1 for two reasons: in C++ you *can* perform the cast, and therefore this basic operation is still "something you can do in both C and C++".  The expression in each language is not important; that they do the same thing is.  And that leads me to the second reason: You can do OO in C.  Have a look at GObject.  The syntax isn't as nice as C, but it's still possible.

Comment: @cdhowie #1 is bogus because I never said C++ *can't* do the cast, I said it was mandatory in C++.  I'll concede the 2nd point since  `can't be done` was a bit overreaching.  I want my 1/2 point back!

Comment: @SiegeX: Well, if you consider only syntax, you can't do *anything at all* in Perl that you can do in C.  Syntax is 100% irrelevant here, only that the *same operations* are possible.  (And I am *not* equating Perl and C; there are things in C you cannot do in Perl without using native libraries.)

Comment: The first C++ compilers were simply C++ to C translators.  So, at that point, everything done in C++, including all the OO functionality, was done in C.

Comment: @Etienne: yes, you can do OO in C, and they're not "fake".  They're just not built-in

Comment: I don't believe this is a meaningful answer. Having to explicitly cast isn't a big deal - and if anything, is slightly better in a strict typing sense. To put it another way, I think Pascal and C are near identical whereas C and C++ are much less so. Spelling and syntax issues are superficial and trivial. Semantics are not. The need for more explicit casts is semantics, true, but insignificant next to other differences between C and C++.

Comment: @Keith: C++ has been fully compiled from day one. Why would it matter that C was used as an intermediate language? The Glasgow Haskell Compiler still uses C as an intermediate language. What does that mean? Is Haskell not "a real language" until it compiles straight to machine code? :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: Not at all.  I was trying to make the point that, if C++ can be compiled to C, then there is nothing that can be done in C++ that cannot be done in C.  I think that compiling to C can be the right choice in a lot of cases, since it makes your system immediately portable to a huge number of platforms.